# VBA - sum specific cells

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I apologise beforehand if some elements of my question seem a little vague, however I will aim to be as specific as I can.

I have an excel workbook which currently contains daily stock trading information. Each day's trading activity is contained on its own worksheet. The screenshot attached below is an example/mockup of what a day's trading activity worksheet looks like.

[image: daily worksheet]

There is also a master worksheet in the workbook which contains the week to date and month to date trading figures of every client. I've attached another example screenshot below:

[image: master]

With this in mind, would it be possible to use VBA in order for it to check the client name in each individual day worksheet, check the column K for gross commission and sum the total figure on the master worksheet?

For example, if client A traded 50,000 on 12/10/2018 and 100,000 on 13/10/2018, their week to date revenue on the master worksheet would show 150,000 after running the VBA.

I do currently have a VBA within the workbook which sums up total trading revenue to a master worksheet, however I'd like to add to it with the above idea. Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated as I have not been able to figure it out. Thank you.

```
Sub AutoSum()
Dim wscount As Long
Dim i As Long
     wscount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
 For i = 1 To wscount
Sheets(i).Select
Range("K3").Select
 Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
Dim cel1 As String, cel2 As String
cel1 = ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).End(xlUp).Address
cel2 = ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Address
ActiveCell.Value = "=sum(" & (cel1) & ":" & (cel2) & ")"
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, becuase of the complexity of the macro, I can't coee it for you, but I'll suggest what you can do:

1. You need to have all the clients in a list (I guess you have it in yoor mastersheet)
2. For each client, yo need to find where he7she is located in each worksheet, so, for each client, and for each worksheet, you use Application.WorkSheetFunction.Match, so you get the row where the client is (we will name it row)
3. then, you will use an accumulative variable to save the sum for each worksheet, yo you code totalsum = totalsum + worksheet(j).cells(row,11 --> *which means K*)

Finally,I'll recommend you a form where you post initial date and final date, so you get the value according to dates

Hope it helps a little